# set package version in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I use Ansible to configure a system which includes installing many packages.

Must I set the version number to the packages? My understanding is If I do not set the versions to the individual package, then next time when I rerun the Ansible, it will install the latest versions of the packages, then I am afraid the latest versions of some package will be incompatible with the latest versions of other packages, Am I correct?

Here is an example how currently I set the versions:

```
- name: install apache-airflow[postgres, s3, ...]
  become_user: root
  pip:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    version: "{{ item.version }}"
  with_items:
     - { name: apache-airflow, version: 1.10.3}
     - { name: postgres, version: 2.2.2} 
     - { name: s3, version: 3.0.0 } 
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that you are using an older version of ansible than 2.8, since [`with_items` does not appear in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html).

the best advice is to call your favorite python package manager (such as pip) directly from an ansible playbook. this approach let each tool do what it does best :)

using a package manager such as pip, the (package) dependencies are stored in a [requirements file](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-files).

for instance, you can have an ansible [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) that invokes `pip`. something like:

```
tasks:
  - name: install python dependencies
    command: pip install -r requirement.txt
```

would also offer you to use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) whenever you can, which create a python environment for your python project and thus avoiding package conflicts.

`virtualenv` should be installed before you are installing other package dependenceis.

assuming that you are using python version 3, it will look something like that:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
$ virtualenv --python=`which python3` venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

you can also place the above snippet in a shell script, then invoke the shell script using ansible `command`. this will install `virtualenv`, activate it and finally install the python packages.

Comment: Thanks Mr. yes my ansible < 2.8. what is "call your favorite python package manager (such as pip) directly from an ansible playbook. " I did install packages using pip in Ansible. see the 3rd line of my code which showed "pip:", or do you mean sth. else?

Comment: regarding to "the (package) dependencies are stored in a requirements file." do you mean I can define a requirements file myself and tell pip to install using that? I can do that but I believe the result is the same as using version: "{{ item.version }}" I mention in the above code. by reading the https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-files you showed me, I feel that pip has no way to avoid the conflict. the only way to avoid that is to restrict dependency using requirements file or use  version: "{{ item.version }}". please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user389955: i've update my answer per your questions. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. 1) I see. you mean call pip using command not ansible pip. 2) I will try requirements.txt. I guess requirements.txt and with_items work the same meaning. Both of them are to get the fixed package version right? you use requirements.txt rather than with_items because your system is ansible 2.8 I guess. I will definitely try requirements.txt to see if it works better.

Comment: @user389955: correct, rather than using `pip` ansible module, use `command` ansible module to invoke `pip` and specify a `reuqirements.txt`